# Confusions about Pesaran & Timmermann test (2009 version)

Tags: forecasting, accuracy

I am learning about Pesaran Timmermann test (2009) for directional accuracy and I have troubles understanding its formula. Here I use notation and arrangement used in Pönkä (2017):

$$PT=(T-1)(S^{-1}_{yy,w}S_{y\hat{y},w}S^{-1}_{\hat{y}\hat{y},w}S_{\hat{y}y,w}) \sim {\chi}^2_1, $$

$$S_{yy,w}=(T-1)^{-1}Y'M_wY, $$
$$S_{\hat{y}\hat{y},w}=(T-1)^{-1}\hat{Y}'M_w\hat{Y}, $$
$$S_{\hat{y}y,w}=(T-1)^{-1}\hat{Y}'M_wY,$$
$$S_{y\hat{y},w}=(T-1)^{-1}Y'M_w\hat{Y}, $$
$$M_w=I_{T-1}-W(W'W)^{-1}W', $$
$$W=(\tau_{T-1},Y_{-1},\hat{Y}_{-1}),$$

From what I understand the series $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$ are column vectors of 0 and 1. First is generated by change in actual values $\Delta a=a_t-a_{t-1}$, and it takes zero when $\Delta a\leqslant0$ and one otherwise. Similar for $\hat{Y}$ but with forecast $\Delta f=f_t-f_{t-1}$ and if $\Delta f\leqslant0$ zero, if not - one. Is this correct? I am browsing couple of sources and I get more and more confused with many different explanations. Can anyone familiar with this tests confirm whether I understand it correctly?

Secondly, I am also quite confused when it comes to meaning of each part of the test formula. According to my source (and the others i saw) it goes like this: $T$ is the number of observations (sometimes its called $n$) $Y=(y_2,...,y_T)'$ and $\hat{Y}=(\hat{y}_2,...,\hat{y}_T)'$ are two series series of one and zeros generated by deltas above ($Y$ by actual($a$) values and $\hat{Y}$ by forecasts($f$)) and $'$ means they are column vectors. Assuming I am right with those deltas, it makes sense that index starts from $2$ because first observation is always "lost" (calculating difference between time series and its lag). In last formula of matrix $W$, $Y_{-1}=(y_1,...,y_{T-1})$ and $\hat{Y}_{-1}=(\hat{y}_1,...,\hat{y}_{T-1})$. What does those two vector represents? How do I calculate them? Here index starts with $1$ and end with $T-1$ which is really confusing. The $\tau_{T-1}$ is $(T-1)x1$ vector of ones (self explanatory). Last thing that I am not certain is $I_{T-1}$ in $M_w$ part. Usually $I$ stands for indicator function, but if I am correct here is suppose to be a vector(?).

I red Pesaran and Timmermann (2009) paper but I am still not sure whether I fully understand it. I will edit this post if more info is required.

References:

Pönkä, H. (2017). Predicting the direction of US stock markets using industry returns. Empirical Economics, 52(4), 1451-1480.

Pesaran, M. H., & Timmermann, A. (2009). Testing dependence among serially correlated multicategory variables. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 104(485), 325-337.

Comment: Hi: I was trying locate ponka 2014 but was unable to. could you be a little more specific ?

Comment: I added references. Also the year was wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks, the 2014 one is available for free but 2017 isn't. hopefully it doesn't matter. I'm familiar with pesaran and timmerman test but not the ponja paper. I'll try to read it when I have time but hopefully someone else will beat me to it because I don't have a lot these days. Eliott and Timmerman have a nice  text called economic forecasting but I can't recall if there's anything in it about what you asked. Still,  I recommend it. The econometric forecasting literature is BEYOND HUGE and they do a pretty nice job with bookifying it.

Comment: Also, I can't say with certainty but you may have been better off sending your question to economics.stackexchange.com. I don't think you can send now since cross-posting is frowned upon. This list ( crossvalidated ) is amazing but that question falls under econometrics IMHO.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I am going to check literature you recommended. I know there is lot of sources but they all use similar notations and I have hard times understanding what they mean. It is a shame I did not thought of checking other stackexchange subsites... If you find any paper with clear explanation of entire formula I would be very glad (now I am going to check Elliot and Timmermann as you advised). Btw, what software you use to calculating Pesaran & Timmermann test (2009)?

Comment: Hi Alexandros: I've never calculated it but, if I was going to, I would probably check R for a package and, if that didn't exist, then I'd try to write it myself as a function.  I printed out everything out ( Pesaran and Timmerman paper and Ponka paper and your question ) and have it all in my bag but it may take me a while to read it because I have a lot going on. I do look forward to it though and wish that I could look at it immediately.